# Python Programming involving Side Effects

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm new to this so I apologize for any of my mistakes.

This is my code:

```
def main():
    global user_input
    user_input = [0,1,2]
    final = fibonacci(user_input)
    return final

def append_fibonacci(integer_list):
    new_list = []
    while integer_list[1] < 40:
        integer_list[0], integer_list[1] = integer_list[1], integer_list[0]+integer_list[1] 
        new_list.append(integer_list[0])
    return(new_list)

def fibonacci(max):
    final = append_fibonacci(max)
    print("Enter a non-negative integer >")
    print("The Fibonacci series starts with:",final)
```

My error is the outcome only prints:

> `The Fibonacci series starts with: [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]`

When it's suppose to print whatever other inputs (such as `inputs: 8` / `outputs: The Fibonacci series starts with: [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]` , `inputs: 0` / `outputs: The Fibonacci series starts with: []`, `inputs: 1` / `Output: The Fibonacci series starts with: [1, 1]` & `inputs: six` / `Output: six is not a non-negative integer` ).

I'm unsure if and where to use the `(if, else statements)` and if to check if it `(.isdigit)` or `(isinstance, str)`.

Can someone help me or give me the answer? Thank you for your time in assisting me.

This is the question below.

---

The `main` function must input a string. If the string does not represent a non-negative integer, then it should print a warning message. If it does represent a non-negative integer, then it should call the `fibonacci` function to create the `list` of Fibonacci numbers that are less than or equal to the non-negative integer and output this `list`. The `fibonacci` function should call the `append_fibonacci` function multiple times to create the Fibonacci `list`.

If you use a function from an imported module in your function, you must import that module inside your function.

Comment: You've not told the code to print anything else other than `print("Enter a non-negative integer >")`
 `print("The Fibonacci series starts with:",final)`?

Comment: You could start by implementing the first sentence of the specification.  When you know that works, move on to the second sentence.  When that works, move on in the smallest possible increments.

Answer (score 0):

Get input from users, you should use `input()` method. In `main()` function, `user_input = input("Enter a non-negative integer >")` will work. Also avoid using global variables. You don't need input variable as a global variable in this code, simply delete that line.

Use `int()` to check if the input is integer or not. You can handle the error message using `try...except`. Use `if...else` to check if the number negative or not.

Your code should look something like this:

```
def main():
    user_input = input("Enter a non-negative integer > ")
    try:
        if int(user_input) < 0:
            print('{} is not a non-negative integer'.format(user_input))
        else:
            final = fibonacci(int(user_input))
            print("The Fibonacci series integer_lists with: ", final)
    except ValueError:
        print('"{}" is not a non-negative integer'.format(user_input))

def append_fibonacci(integer_list):
    if len(integer_list) < 2:
        integer_list.append(1)
    else:
        integer_list.append(integer_list[-1] + integer_list[-2])
    return integer_list

def fibonacci(max):
    integer_list = []
    if max == 0:
        return integer_list
    else:
        while len(integer_list) < 2 or integer_list[-1] + integer_list[-2] <= max:
                integer_list = append_fibonacci(integer_list)
        return integer_list
```

Comment: I had to change the ( def append_fibonacci(max): ) to ( def append_fibonacci(integer_list): ). When I ran it through the quiz, I received 3 RuntimeErrorElement & 1 TypeError. I'm going to add more details in the comment cause if I add more stuff to the question above, it would be too long or someone wouldn't understand.

Comment: This is what were shown in my errors: (start line) RuntimeErrorElement(RuntimeError,Error on line 7:
    final = fibonacci(int(user_input)))
RuntimeErrorElement(RuntimeError,Error on line 21:
    final = append_fibonacci(max))
RuntimeErrorElement(RuntimeError,Error on line 15:
    while integer_list[1] <= max:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method') (end line)

Comment: Write user-defined functions with these function headers:     
                                                                                         1. def append_fibonacci(integer_list): {Modify the argument list of integers by appending a new integer that is the sum of the last two integers in the list. If the list has fewer than two elements add the int object 1 to the list.}

Comment: 2. def fibonacci(max): {Return a list that contains all Fibonacci numbers that are less than or equal to the argument integer.}

Comment: 3. def main(): {Input a non-negative integer, n. Output the Fibonacci numbers that are less than or equal to that number, in order. If the input is not a valid non-negative integer, output a warning message.}

Comment: you're a genius!!! Thank you. It was successful, I just had to do a little minor editing of the messages but it work. I am really grateful for the assistance provided. I am going to add the code I had to use below in a comment.

Comment: I'll be going through the code to have a better understanding but I would like to ask a question. This question I posted is a 2 part question. Can/Should I post the other part in here also or do I need to post it as a new question?

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is with this statement `while integer_list[1] < 40`. Independent of the input you pass to the function it will output Fibonacci numbers less than 40. Second problem is the `user_input` list you pass through functions which is completely unnecessary. You just need to pass `max` number and your program will output Fibonacci numbers less than or equal to `max`. Third problem is you do not have a mechanism to check whether the input is a valid non-negative integer.

Here is the code:

```py
def main():
    _max = ""
    while not _max.isnumeric():
        _max = input("Enter a non-negative integer >")
    _max = int(_max)
    final = append_fibonacci(max)
    print("The Fibonacci series starts with:",final)
    return final

def append_fibonacci(_max):
    if _max==0:
        return []
    fibonacci = []
    x=1
    y=1
    while y <= _max:
        x, y = y, x+y
        fibonaccis.append(x)
    return fibonacci

main()
```

Comment: I'm still missing "def append_fibonacci(integer_list):" because if I input the solution, it say's (start line) Expected method 'append_fibonacci' to be defined as:

def append_fibonacci(integer_list):
   ... (end line)

Comment: So, based on my solution you can write your own code. I don't know what the requirements are.

Comment: I just included some more details below in a comment. I will try to add more stuff to your code and make the attempts. I'm sort of understanding what is being written.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    user_input = input("Enter a non-negative integer >")
    try:
        if int(user_input) < 0:
            print('{} is not a non-negative integer'.format(user_input))
        else:
            final = fibonacci(int(user_input))
            print("The Fibonacci series starts with:", final)
    except ValueError:
        print('{} is not a non-negative integer'.format(user_input))

def append_fibonacci(integer_list):
    if len(integer_list) < 2:
        integer_list.append(1)
    else:
        integer_list.append(integer_list[-1] + integer_list[-2])
    return integer_list

def fibonacci(max):
    integer_list = []
    if max == 0:
        return integer_list
    else:
        while len(integer_list) < 2 or integer_list[-1] + integer_list[-2] <= max:
                integer_list = append_fibonacci(integer_list)
    return integer_list
```

Comment: In the light of your other "answer" that appeared to be an addition to your question (and you still didn't delete), is *this* an answer, or yet another amendment?